# sum by rows (include all columns) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this structure of table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ID-Prod | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |....
-----------------------------------------------------------------
012        213       879       516         213       435
013        953       837                   361       862
014        123       583       879         519       573
015        963  
016        798
```

ID-Prod is the primary key, **i would like to sum all the values for each product**
for example

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID-Prod | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |....|         Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
012        213       879       516         213       435           213+879+516+213+435
013        953       837                   361       862                  .....
014        123       583       879         519       573                  .....
015        963  
016        798
```

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes? The table structure might be better but the question itself is valid and answerable.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I guess because of "*the question shows no research effort*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*,
        COALESCE(Monday, 0) +
        COALESCE(Tuesday, 0) +
        COALESCE(Wednesday, 0) +
        COALESCE(Thursday, 0) +
        COALESCE(Friday, 0) AS total
FROM    mytable t
```

Comment: Thank's a lot "COALESCE" is new for me. it resolve my problem